# What should be sent from a client to an OAuth provider

Tags: oauth

Alright, I'm in the process of making a C# application that uses an API from a website, and they use OAuth.  I'm super new to OAuth, so how can I go about making a proper request.  What stuff should I have in my query string.  Are there any HTTP Headers that I would need to have set?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All requests will need to have the oauth_consumerkey, oauth_token, oauth_version, oauth_nonce, oauth_timestamp, oauth_signature_method, and oauth_signature added either to the querystring (for HTTP GET), form fields (for HTTP POST), or to an authorization header.

Unless you are coding to learn, you should consider implementing a pre-made library for the API. [Twitterizer](http://www.twitterizer.net), for the twitter api, for example.

If you're interested, I released a small package to assist developers when creating OAuth. It will handle request signing behind the scenes. It's available on the [Twitterizer Downloads page](http://www.twitterizer.net/downloads/) as "Standalone OAuth library".

Comment: Alright, I'm taking a look at your OAUth Library, and it looks really good.  Could you help me set it up to make a basic OAuth request and authorization?